# Displaying duplicate text within a JSON array using php

Tags: php

I have an array inside a php file in JSON format. I want to display the most frequent element of the name object:

```php
<?php

$mydata = '[{"data":[{"name":"amr selim","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"ame selim","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"Amr Selim","phone":"12345"},{"name":"3mr","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"x","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"mr ","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"Amr sleem","phone":"12345"},
{"name":"\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"12345"},{"name":"Tv l Pc","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0625\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"12345"},{"name":"Amr Selim","phone":"12345"},{"name":"Tv pc","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"0012345"},{"name":"Amr Selim","phone":"0012345"},{"name":"Efham Computer","phone":"0012345"},{"name":"Tv 3l Pc","phone":"0012345"},{"name":"\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645","phone":"0012345"},{"name":"Amr Selim","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"+12345"},{"name":"\u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"+12345"},{"name":"\u0645. \u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"12345"},{"name":"\u0645. \u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0641\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0645\u0628\u064a\u0648\u062a\u0631","phone":"12345"},{"name":"Amr Selim","phone":"12345"},{"name":"amr Selim","phone":"12345"},{"name":"amr Selim","phone":"12345"}],"info":[{"lastid":"437397286","usernum":"12345","cantry":"EG"}]}]';

$task_array = json_decode($mydata,true);
print_r(array_count_values($task_array[0]["data"]));

?>
```

I'm trying to get the most frequent text in the **name** object
which in this case will be **"amr selim"**.

I tried using this code but I get an error: *"Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!"*

I don't know where to start, how to show the most frequent names in the array.
can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_count_values` function as follows.

```
array_count_values(array_column($task_array[0]["data"], 'name'));
```